# How to read google tango translation (delta) on unity?

Tags: google-project-tango

I am trying to add a pause button for a google tango game on unity, but unsure how to pause google tango without resseting it...

Tried to look the web for a tutorial on how to read google tango xyz translation and quatreunion rotationto the translation manually but could not find a usefull tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two kinds of pause you can implement.

1. Pause at the current location, and resume moving from the same location.

For this one, you will need to manually save a transformation offset, and apply it after resume the application.

2. Pause at the current location, and resume moving form the latest tracked location.

For this one, you could just keep use the motion tracking pose in the background, but don't update the UI or 3D object when the app is paused.